# Pyrogram Chat_Member.Status check doesn't work

Tags: bots, telegram, pyrogram

I am trying to write a code for a bot using pyrogram, where it should process a command only from admins or owners. This is my code

```
@app.on_message(filters.chat(TARGET) & filters.command("start"))
async def start(client, message):
    # Check if the sender is the owner or admin of the chat
    chat_member_info = await client.get_chat_member(TARGET, message.from_user.id)    
    chat_member_info_status = chat_member_info.status
#checkpoint 1
    await message.reply_text(f'You are {chat_member_info_status}')
    if chat_member_info_status == 'ChatMemberStatus.OWNER' or chat_member_info_status == 'ChatMemberStatus.ADMINISTRATOR':
        # Do A
       )
    else:
       #  Do B
```

Bot returns me 'You are ChatMemberStatus.OWNER' in my checkpoint 1 but for some reason, 'if' function never works and it program goes to 'Do B' every time...

Will appreciate any help, I am very new to pyrogram. thanks!

Tried to check first_name as a test instead and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`ChatMemberStatus.OWNER` is an ENUM, you're using it as a string.

---

You'll need something like:

```
from pyrogram.enums import ChatMemberStatus

chat_member_info = await client.get_chat_member(TARGET, message.from_user.id)    
chat_member_info_status = chat_member_info.status

is_admin = chat_member_info_status in [ChatMemberStatus.OWNER, ChatMemberStatus.ADMINISTRATOR]

if is_admin:
    # Do A
else:
    # Do B
```